# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on VSCode startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

I keep receiving this message when I startup VSCode:

```
[2022-08-01 13:59:02.322] [renderer1] [error] net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET: Error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:105:7047)
at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (node:events:390:28)
[2022-08-01 13:59:04.114] [renderer1] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://vscodeexperiments.azureedge.net/experiments/vscode-experiments.json {}
```

I've done a fresh reinstall of VSCode, cleared out my .vscode file, and tried disabling my antivirus as well as my firewall to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system PATH `'http_proxy'` and `'https_proxy'` and delete them.
Restart and try again.